# Parse sqlalchemy.engine.result.RowProxy in Python

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I have a problem, I can't parse result given from my sql (postgres) query. For query I am using db function written earlier (s_check()). Here is snippet:

```
def s_check():
    for json_str in db.engine.execute("select to_json(s_check())"):
        print json_str
        // ('{"query":"each device has user","pass":true}',)
        print type(json_str)
        // <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.result.RowProxy'>
        print json_str[0]
        // {"query":"each device has user","pass":true}
        print json_str[0]['pass']
        // TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

It is funny that this doesn't work locally, when I deploy this code on server my app is working and without this error.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the db function `s_check` is exactly the same on your dev / prod environments? After making sure of that, I'd check that your connection to the DB is set up in exactly the same way. Looks like locally, `json_str[0]` is a `string` but on prod it is a `dict`. Can you add a debugging line to verify that?

Comment: Hi again, thanks for comment. Yes, I am sure that both functions (s_check and to_json) are same on dev and prod environments. Further, I managed to debug it on prod and yes, json_str[0] is string on my dev side and is dict on my prod side. But I still can't find the reason for this behavior.

Comment: Further, print outputs on my dev side:                                                              ({u'query': u'each device has user', u'pass': False},)                   
<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.result.RowProxy'>                                                          
{u'query': u'each device has user', u'pass': False}                            
<type 'dict'>

Comment: Furtherer. Postgres client_encoding is utf-8 on both sides

Comment: Are the table definitions the same on both places? Postgres version? Also make sure all the python libraries (especially sqlalchemy) are the same versions in both environments. Something has to be different between the two environments. Do you have any explicit logic anywhere in your application that does things differently on dev vs prod? Sorry, I'm out of ideas. But it seems the bug is essentially not in your code posted here.

Comment: Table definitions are same on both sides. PostgreSQL 9.4.3 is used on prod and PostgreSQL 9.3.9 is used on dev side.  I'll read more about it, hope I found solution. Thank you, again.

Comment: Nope, on new Postgres 9.4.4 everything stays the same except my queries run a lot slower :(